# Unable to install Meld by MacPorts

Tags: macos, installation, macports, meld

I found that other people too have had trouble in installing Meld to Mac by MacPorts.

I run

```
sudo port install meld
```

I get

```
sudo port install meld  
 --->  Activating shared-mime-info @0.60_0
Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error: /opt/local/bin/update-mime-database already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port shared-mime-info.
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: py25-gnome gconf gtk2 shared-mime-info orbit2 libidl gnome-vfs desktop-file-utils gnome-mime-data libbonobo libbonoboui libglade2 libgnome esound audiofile libgnomecanvas libart_lgpl libgnomeui gnome-icon-theme hicolor-icon-theme icon-naming-utils p5-xml-simple p5-xml-namespacesupport p5-xml-sax gnome-keyring libtasn1 py25-gtk py25-cairo py25-numpy py25-nose py25-gobject py25-orbit
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

**How can you install Meld to Mac?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that MacPorts worked to install meld, but it didn't work straight away as advertised.

After running and installing all the dependencies, it failed, and gave a cryptic log message similar to the one in this question (but not identical).

After a bit of digging around I found I had to do the following:

Make sure I had properly agreed to the license for XCode

```
xcodebuild -license
```

Install the Xcode command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

Install rarian (it seems to be a dependency that MacPorts failed to recognize)

```
sudo port install rarian
```

The latter instructions come from here:
http://www.codez.co.uk/2014/02/meld-on-mac-osx-mavericks-10-9/
and this was the last step before I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 5):

As rspeed said, you probably had a bad install or upgrade that created that file. Alternately, you installed something outside of macports into the /opt/local tree (though I'm not sure how you would have ended up doing that). I recommend just doing a force activate of the shared-mime-info port, then trying to reinstall meld.

```
sudo port activate -f shared-mime-info
sudo port install meld
```

Comment: @Kevin: I get the error: Error: activate does not accept --force

Comment: Sorry, there's no long option for force, rspeed's comment confused me and I didn't bother looking it up ;) Just use -f instead. You should also put it before the action, as in `sudo port -f activate shared-mime-info`

Answer (score 1):

Somehow that file already exists, probably from a bad uninstall or upgrade.

If you force the install it *probably* won't break anything.

```
sudo port install --force meld
```

Comment: It's actually the shared-mime-info dependency that's having the issue. Only that one should be forced.

Answer (score 1):

Installing meld on OS X 10.10.  For added difficulty, must use OS X's quartz display server (rather than X11 display server):

```
$ sudo port install python27
$ sudo port select --set python python27
$ sudo port install rarian
$ sudo port install pango +no_x11
$ sudo port install gtk2 +quartz
$ sudo port install py27-pygtk +quartz
$ sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents gtk3
$ sudo port install gtk3
$ sudo port uninstall py27-pygtksourceview
$ sudo port install py27-pygtksourceview +quartz
$ sudo port install gnome-desktop
$ sudo port install meld +quartz

$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist

<reboot system...>

$ meld
```

Wow, it works!

Comment: Brew has also nowadays Meld so you could simply run: brew install meld with X11 directly. I would like to have Meld with Qt instead.